# Get specific columns on an Included Entity: Invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'

Tags: database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

One of my linked tables `PropertyInfo` has an image column, which I don't want to retrieve, every time I `.Include()` that table. Therefore I took the following approach:

```
user = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == idOfUser)
.Include(x => x.Co.PropertyInfo.Select(i =>
   new PropertyModel(
     Id = i.Id, 
     Date = i.Date, 
     CompanyNumber = i.CompanyNumber,
     LinkedCategories = i.LinkedCategories,
     LinkedReviews = i.LinkedReviews)))
.ThenInclude(x => x.LinkedCategories)
.ThenInclude(x => x.LinkedReviews)))
.Take(1)
.FirstOrDefault()
```

This code throws an error:
`The expression [EXPRESSION I PASTED ABOVE] is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'....`

Is it possible that I'm trying to assign the linked Tables like `LinkedCategories` and `LinkedReviews` which are being `ThenInclud-ed`? Or is this related to something else? How can I include entities without querying for all of the columns?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this if you have an empty constructor in PropertyModel.
You definitely can make it with single query. I don't know what is the structure of your models. For more accurate answer, you can share them.

```
user = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == idOfUser)
.Select(i => new PropertyModel
{
    Id = i.PropertyInfo.Id, 
    Date = i.PropertyInfo.Date, 
    CompanyNumber = i.PropertyInfo.CompanyNumber,
    LinkedCategories = i.PropertyInfo.LinkedCategories,
    LinkedReviews = i.PropertyInfo.LinkedReviews
})
.Take(1)
.FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: One note. Remove Includes, they are not needed.

Comment: Just waiting for the models relations post